# Angular-cli : Using ng lint

Tags: jslint, angular-cli

I'm aware the angular-cli uses codelyzer which uses lint.js

When using the command:
`ng lint`

Can it automatically fix formatting? or will it only notify of formatting errors?

`ng lint --help` outputs all help commands for the angular-cli.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Updated answer for Angular **CLI v6.x, 7.x, 8.x**:

**`ng lint <project-name> --fix`**

where <project-name> is "name:" from package.json

-- answer for Angular **CLI v1.x** --

**`ng lint -fix`**

-- Original answer below --

To have **tslint autofix** many errors run the following in the root of your code. Obviously it can only autofix simpler issues like let -> const, "" -> ' etc.

```
npx tslint src/**/*.ts --fix
```

Yesterday I did this to auto-fix hundreds of let -> const issues in our fairly large code bases. Just reviewing the changes before committing took long enough, manually fixing them all would have taken over a day.

Comment: a fix that --fix options cannot do by itself is no-console. Sad because it will be useful to conditionally delete debug console log.

Comment: If you have changed your project name and or the name in the pkg.json and this does not work, check your angular.json file and ensure the name in the pkg.json is listed under projects.

where <project-name> is listed under "projects" in your angular.json

Answer (score 12):

For Angular 6.0+ you can run `ng lint` with autofix like so:

```
ng lint <project> --fix
```

where `<project>` is the name you gave to your project when running `ng new`.

Learn more here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/lint

Answer (score 5):

The functionality you are asking about is partially available these days in [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) using the [TSLint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint) which does support Auto Fixing for some (but not all) of the default TSLint warnings.

I've been using it for a few weeks now and I find it quite helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, Angular 6.0 and newer supports this functionality natively.

---

For pre-Angular 6.0:

`ng lint` runs the [tslint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint) (TypeScript linter) which just prints out linting errors. AFAIK, it doesn't directly allow fixing found problems (**as of Nov 16**)

There are projects as `tslint-fix` which aim for fixing a set of so-called auto-fixable problems.

Comment: A real shame, so I have to manually check and fix my formatting to keep tslint happy?

Comment: Seems so. It's the only option for all the non-auto-fixable problems anyway. Or you can try to experiment with the `tslint-fix` for the auto-fixables.

Comment: Cheers, will check it out

Comment: `ng lint <proj> --fix` as others said before

Comment: @netalex Reflecting that in the answer now.